# Maximize system of linear equations

Tags: optimization, systems-of-equations, linear-programming

Suppose you have the system

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 3\\
1 & 7\\
5 & 9\\
2 & 4\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\\b_4\end{bmatrix}
$$

How could one find scalars $x$ and $y$ such that $b_1+b_2+b_3+b_4$ is maximized? I can see the math behind it as I just took Theory of Linear Algebra, but am stuck on the question.

**EDIT**: it must be that $0\leq x\leq 1$, $0\leq y\leq 1$, and $x+y=1$.

Answer (score 6):

$4x+3y=b_1$
$x+7y=b_2$
$5x+9y=b_3$
$2x+4y=b_4$
Add them up we can get $12x+23y=b_1+b_2+b_3+b_4=12(x+y)+11y$
Since $x+y=1$,  $b_1+b_2+b_3+b_4=12+11y$
In order to maximize the sum, y has to be as large as it can be, thus $y=1,x=0$

Comment: That's much simpler than linear programming.

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
4x+3y&=b_1\\
x+7y&=b_2\\
5x+9y&=b_3\\
2x+4y&=b_4
\end{align}

Since the coefficients of these systems are all positive and there are no restriction on $b_i$, we can set $x$ and $y$ to be as large or small as we want and $b_1+b_2+b_3+b_4\in (-\infty,\infty)$

This would of course be another question if there were positive and negative coefficients in both $x$ and $y$

Comment: I forgot to mention this above and I will edit the main question. It must be the case that $0\leq x\leq1$, $0\leq y\leq1$, and $x+y=1$.

Comment: Please make an edit of your answer. The question has been specified by the OP. Your answer doesn´t fit any more to the question.

Answer (score 1):

First note
$$
b_1 + b_2 + b_3 + b_4 
= (4 + 1 + 5 + 2) x + (3 + 7 + 9 + 4)
= 12 x + 23 y
$$
then we can formulate it as linear program
$$
\begin{array}{rr}
\max & c^\top u \\
\text{w.r.t.} & A u = b \\
& B u \le d \\
& u \ge 0
\end{array}
$$
for cost vector $c = (12, 23)^\top$, vector of unknowns $u = (x, y)^\top$ and constraints
$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\quad
b =
\begin{pmatrix}
1
\end{pmatrix}
\\
B = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\quad
d = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
As a problem with only $2$ unknowns, it can be solved graphically:

[image]
([Large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Advp.png))

The blue lines and half spaces show the constraints $u \ge 0$ and $B u \le d$. The red line is the constraint $A u = b$.
The yellow lines show the cost isolines, the lowest one is $c = 0$, in the middle $c = 10$ and above $c = 20$.

The set of feasible solutions $u$ consists of the red line clamped to the box $[0,1]^2$.

The maximum is determined by the highest possible cost isoline, thus $12 x + 23 y = c$ which intersects the point $(0, 1)^\top$, thus $12 \cdot 0 + 23 \cdot 1 = 23 = c$.

This gives the maximal solution $u = (0, 1)^\top$ with $c^\top u = 23$.